# What is FULL keyword for in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, keyword

MySQL isn't supporting `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Then, what is the keyword `FULL` in MySQL is for?

I don't see `FULL` in [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) list.

However, I'm not getting a syntax error on `FULL` when I put together a query 
involving `FULL JOIN` in MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't posted your query, so of course it's impossible to answer your question definitively; but most likely, `full` is being interpreted as a table alias. For example:

```
SELECT full.c1,
       t2.c2
  FROM t1 full
  JOIN t2
    ON full.id = t2.id
;
```

where `full` is an alternative name for `t1` for use inside the query. (This is useful when the table appears multiple times in the query and you need to distinguish the uses, or when you have a long table-name that becomes a distraction when you prefix all the columns with their table-names, or whatnot.)

Comment: yes, that should be it. i'm getting the same thing to some other non-keyword in place of 'full' there. thx for clarification. didn't check it all before asking.

Comment: I logged [Bug #69858 Make FULL a reserved word](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69858).